# Remove duplicate from array and add its corresponding value

Tags: php, arrays

> I have an associative array.Which is given below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 99
        [email] => test@gmail.com

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 5.10
        [email] => test@gmail.com

    )

)
```

I want to remove duplicate email from array and add its amount to corresponding one. I tried php function array_unique() but it give me data with only single amount.

My current output is

```
Array
    (
        [amount] => 99
        [email] => test@gmail.com

    )
```

But i want output like

```
 Array
    (
        [amount] => 104.1
        [email] => test@gmail.com

    )
```

Comment: 1. *I tried* Then show us your attempt(s)! 2. What is your current output and what is the expected one?

Comment: When you say add, do you want to sum the amounts together or replace the amount in one array with the new amount ?

Comment: Just another job for [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you can do:

```
$arr = array(
    array('amount' => 99, 'email' => 'test@gmail.com'),
    array('amount' => 5.10, 'email' => 'test@gmail.com')
);

$res = array();

foreach ($arr as $bill) {
    if (!isset($res[$bill['email']])) {
        $res[$bill['email']] = 0;
    }

    $res[$bill['email']] += $bill['amount'];
}

// if you want the same output, format the array back to original:
$arr = array();
foreach ($res as $mail => $amount) {
    $arr[] = array('mail' => $mail, 'amount' => $amount);
}
unset($res);
var_dump($arr);
```

Which gives you:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["mail"]=>
    string(14) "test@gmail.com"
    ["amount"]=>
    float(104.1)
  }
}
```

You can check and test here: http://ideone.com/u6tAYv